# Sqlite java and sqlite4java

Tags: java, sqlite

I am trying to build an app as a learning experience. I am getting a null pointer exception, but it is happening the second time the code is being called.

So my code calls this as part of it's startup.

```
// Sanity checks
sanity = new SanityChecks();
logger.info("Checking sanity...");
try {
    sanity.doBasicChecks();
    logger.info("It all looks sane.");
}
catch( final Exception ex){
    logger.error("Something is wrong, we are not sane.  Aborting...", ex);
    stop();
}
```

Other classes are:

```
package nz.co.great_ape.tempusFugit;

import com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLite;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

/**
 * Checks to see if all is ok for standard usage of tempusFugit.
 *
 * Checks for valid paths, existing database etc, if not assumes that
 * this is the first time tempusFugit has been run for this user and
 * tries to set up the basic files and data.
 *
 * @author Rob Brown-Bayliss
 *         Created on 2/11/14
 */
public class SanityChecks {


    public static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AppConsts.LOGGER_NAME);

    public SanityChecks() {
        // todo
        // todo
        SQLite.setLibraryPath(AppConsts.HOME_DIR);   // TODO:  Why is this required?  can we not place the native libs somewhere else or in the jar?
        // todo
        // todo
    }

    /**
     * Performs basic checks to see if it is ok to run the app.  If not it will attempt to
     * set up for first time use.
     *
     * @return true if all is ok
     */
    public boolean doBasicChecks() {
        logger.info("Starting basic checks...");
        if (!HomeDirExists()) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!DatabaseExists()) {
            logger.info("Trying to create a new database.");
            DatabaseUpgrade dug = new DatabaseUpgrade();
            if (!dug.upGrade()) {
                return false;
            }
            logger.info("Created a new database.");
            // At this point a usable database should exist and it should be current
        }
        if (!DatabaseVersionCorrect()) {
//          //  If the database is old we will upgrade it to the current version.
//          DatabaseUpgrade dug = new DatabaseUpgrade();
//          if (!dug.upGrade()) {
//              return false;
//          }
            logger.info("is this it?.");
        }
        //  At this point all basic checks have passed and we are good to go...
        logger.info("Basic checks are complete.  All is good in the universe...");
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Checks if the app home directory exists, if not it tries to create it.
     *
     * @return true if exists or was able to create the directory
     */
    private boolean HomeDirExists() {
        if (!Files.isDirectory(Paths.get(AppConsts.HOME_DIR))) {
            try {
                Files.createDirectory(Paths.get(AppConsts.HOME_DIR));
            }
            catch (IOException io) {
                logger.error("The directory " + AppConsts.HOME_DIR + " does not exist and could not be created.  This is not the best but we can survive.", io);
                return false;
            }
        }
        logger.info("The directory " + AppConsts.HOME_DIR + " exists.  This is good.");
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Checks if the SQLite database exists, if not it tries to create it.
     * or was able to create the database
     *
     * @return true if the database exists
     */
    private boolean DatabaseExists() {
        if (Files.notExists(Paths.get(AppConsts.TF_DATABASE))) {
            logger.error("The database " + AppConsts.TF_DATABASE + " does not exist.  This is bad.");
            return false;
        }
        logger.info("The database " + AppConsts.TF_DATABASE + " exists.  This is good.");
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Checks if the SQLite database is correct for this version.
     *
     * @return true if correct version
     */
    private boolean DatabaseVersionCorrect() {
        Integer expectedVersion = AppConsts.TF_DATABASE_VERSION;
        logger.info("Checking the database version is correct.  Looking for version "+ expectedVersion + "." );
        DatabaseUpgrade dug = new DatabaseUpgrade();
        logger.info("Checking the database version is correct.  Looking for version "+ expectedVersion + "." );
        Integer currentVersion = dug.getVersion();
        if (currentVersion < expectedVersion) {
            logger.info("Expected version " + expectedVersion + ", but database is version " + currentVersion + ".  This is bad.");
            return false;
        }
        logger.info("The database version is correct.  This is good.");
        return true;
    }

}
```

And:

```
package nz.co.great_ape.tempusFugit;

import com.almworks.sqlite4java.*;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

/**
 * Setup the database for current version tempusFugit.  This will upgrade an
 * existing database or create a new empty database if required.
 *
 * @author Rob Brown-Bayliss
 *         Created on 4/11/14
 */
public class
        DatabaseUpgrade {

    public static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AppConsts.LOGGER_NAME);

    private SQLiteConnection dbConn = null;
    private SQLiteQueue      sQueue = null;
    private int currentVersion;

    public DatabaseUpgrade() {

    }

    /**
     * Attempts to upgrade the existing database to the current version, or if
     * there is no existing database then create one suitable for the current app version.
     *
     * @return true if there is a current and usable database
     */
    public boolean upGrade() {
        logger.info("    Started an upgrade on the database, if the database does not exist it will be created at the current version, ");
        logger.info("    if it exists but is an older version it will be upgraded to the current version.");
        if (openDatabase()) {
            currentVersion = getVersion();
            if (currentVersion == AppConsts.FAIL) {
                logger.info("Database version is unknown.  The file will be deleted and a new database created.  We can survive this.");
                // TODO:  Ask user if we should delete the old one or make a backup?
                closeDatabase();
                deleteDatabase();
                openDatabase();
            }
            if (currentVersion != AppConsts.TF_DATABASE_VERSION) {
                logger.info("Current Database version is " + currentVersion);
                // TODO:  Backup current database.
                if (currentVersion < 1) {
                    if (!makeVersionOne()) {
                        logger.error("Unable to upgrade the database.  This is VERY bad.");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                currentVersion = 1;
            }
            closeDatabase();  // good practice
        }
        logger.info("The database is the current version.  This is good.");
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Turns a blank SQLite database into a tempusFugit version 1 database by
     * adding the required tables and data.
     */
    private boolean makeVersionOne() {
        logger.info("Attempting to upgrade to version 1.");
        String CT_SQL = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dbVersion (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, version INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE, ";
        CT_SQL = CT_SQL + "upgraded INTEGER(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT (strftime('%s','now'))); ";
        String IN_SQL = "INSERT INTO dbVersion(version) values (1); ";
        try {
            execSQL("BEGIN TRANSACTION; ");
            execSQL(CT_SQL);  // create the table
            execSQL(IN_SQL);  // insert the record
            execSQL("COMMIT; ");
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("Attempted upgrade of " + AppConsts.TF_DATABASE + " to version 1 has failed.  This is VERY bad.", ex);
            return false;
        }
        logger.info("The database has been upgraded to version 1.  This is good.");
        return true;
    }

    private Integer execSQL(String SQL) {
        return sQueue.execute(new SQLiteJob<Integer>() {
            protected Integer job(SQLiteConnection con) throws SQLiteException {
                SQLiteStatement st = null;
                try {
                    st = con.prepare(SQL);
                    st.step();
                    return AppConsts.SUCCESS;
                }
                catch (Exception ex) {
                    logger.error("Tried to execute SQL: " + SQL, ex);
                    return AppConsts.FAIL;
                }
                finally {
                    if (st != null) {
                        st.dispose();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).complete();
    }

    /**
     * Gets the current database version
     *
     * @return version as an int
     */
    public int getVersion() {
        return sQueue.execute(new SQLiteJob<Integer>() {
            protected Integer job(SQLiteConnection con) throws SQLiteException {
                SQLiteStatement st = null;
                try {
                    st = con.prepare("SELECT version, upgraded FROM dbVersion ORDER BY upgraded DESC LIMIT 1;");
                    st.step();
                    return st.columnInt(0);
                }
                catch (Exception ex) {
                    logger.error("The database version of " + AppConsts.TF_DATABASE + " is unknown.  This is bad.", ex);
                    return AppConsts.FAIL;
                }
                finally {
                    if (st != null) {
                        st.dispose();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).complete();
    }

    /**
     * Opens an existing SQLite database or creates a new blank database
     * if none exists.
     *
     * @return false if there is a problem.  // TODO: Is it possible to have a problem?
     */
    private boolean openDatabase() {
        try {
            dbConn = new SQLiteConnection(new File(AppConsts.TF_DATABASE));
            dbConn.open(true);
            sQueue = new SQLiteQueue(new File(AppConsts.TF_DATABASE));
            sQueue.start();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("The database " + AppConsts.TF_DATABASE + " could not be opened or created.  This is VERY bad.", ex);
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Closes an open database.
     *
     * @return false if there is a problem.  // TODO: Is it possible to have a problem?
     */
    private boolean closeDatabase() {
        try {
            if (dbConn != null) {
                dbConn.dispose();
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("The database " + AppConsts.TF_DATABASE + " could not be closed.", ex);
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Deletes an existing database.
     *
     * @return false if there is a problem.  // TODO: Is it possible to have a problem?
     */
    private boolean deleteDatabase() {
        try {
            Files.delete(Paths.get(AppConsts.TF_DATABASE));
            logger.info("The database " + AppConsts.TF_DATABASE + " has been deleted.");
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("The database " + AppConsts.TF_DATABASE + " could not be deleted.", ex);
            return false;
        }
    }
}


Plus the constants:

package nz.co.great_ape.tempusFugit;

/**
 * Constants used by tempusFugit
 *
 * @author Rob Brown-Bayliss
 *         Created on 31/10/14
 */
public class AppConsts {

    // Application
    public static final String APP_NAME       = "Tempus Fugit";
    public static final String VERSION_NUMBER = "0.0.1";

    // Debug Mode On-Off
    public static final boolean DEBUG_MODE = true;

    // Data files and paths
    public static final String FS        = System.getProperty("file.separator");
    public static final String HOME_DIR  = System.getProperty("user.home") + FS + ".tempusFugit";  // This is the tempusFugit home, not the users home.
    public static final String USER_NAME = System.getProperty("user.name");

    public static final String LOGGER_NAME = "nz.co.great_ape.tempusFugit";
    public static final String LOG_FILE    = HOME_DIR + FS + "tempusFugit.log";

    // Database
    public static final String TF_DATABASE = HOME_DIR + FS + "tfData.sql";
    public static final int TF_DATABASE_VERSION = 1;  //  This is the current version of the database

    // Error codes
    public static final int UNKNOWN = -1;
    public static final int FAIL    = 0;
    public static final int SUCCESS = 1;

}
```

What I don't know is why the call if (!DatabaseVersionCorrect()) crashes with a null pointer.

Can anyone help here?

This is the stack trace

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:49764,suspend=y,server=n -javaagent:/home/rob/Projects/IntelliJ/plugins/Groovy/lib/agent/gragent.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/home/rob/Projects/tempusFugit/build/classes/main:/home/rob/Projects/tempusFugit/build/resources/main:/home/rob/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.7/2b8019b6249bb05d81d3a3094e468753e2b21311/slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar:/home/rob/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.almworks.sqlite4java/sqlite4java/1.0.392/d6234e08ff4e1607ff5321da2579571f05ff778d/sqlite4java-1.0.392.jar:/home/rob/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.1.2/b316e9737eea25e9ddd6d88eaeee76878045c6b2/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar:/home/rob/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ch.qos.logback/logback-core/1.1.2/2d23694879c2c12f125dac5076bdfd5d771cc4cb/logback-core-1.1.2.jar:/home/rob/Projects/IntelliJ/lib/idea_rt.jar nz.co.great_ape.tempusFugit.MainApp
```

Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:49764', transport: 'socket'
10:43:43.371 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  nz.co.great_ape.tempusFugit - Time flies...
10:43:43.379 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  nz.co.great_ape.tempusFugit - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ESto79osxOY
10:43:43.379 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  nz.co.great_ape.tempusFugit - Tempus Fugit Version: 0.0.1
10:43:43.379 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  nz.co.great_ape.tempusFugit - javafx.runtime.version: 8.0.25-b17
10:43:43.380 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  nz.co.great_ape.tempusFugit - logged on as: rob
10:43:43.383 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  nz.co.great_ape.tempusFugit - Checking sanity...
10:43:43.383 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  nz.co.great_ape.tempusFugit - Starting basic checks...
10:43:43.393 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  nz.co.great_ape.tempusFugit - The directory /home/rob/.tempusFugit exists.  This is good.
10:43:43.394 [JavaFX Application Thread] ERROR nz.co.great_ape.tempusFugit - The database /home/rob/.tempusFugit/tfData.sql does not exist.  This is bad.
10:43:43.394 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  nz.co.great_ape.tempusFugit - Trying to create a new database.
10:43:43.397 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  nz.co.great_ape.tempusFugit -     Started an upgrade on the database, if the database does not exist it will be created at the current version, 
10:43:43.397 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  nz.co.great_ape.tempusFugit -     if it exists but is an older version it will be upgraded to the current version.
Nov 30, 2014 10:43:43 AM com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal log
INFO: [sqlite] DB[1]: instantiated [/home/rob/.tempusFugit/tfData.sql]
Nov 30, 2014 10:43:43 AM com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal log
INFO: [sqlite] Internal: loaded sqlite4java-linux-amd64-1.0.392 from /home/rob/.tempusFugit/libsqlite4java-linux-amd64-1.0.392.so
Nov 30, 2014 10:43:43 AM com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal log
INFO: [sqlite] Internal: loaded sqlite 3.8.7, wrapper 1.3
Nov 30, 2014 10:43:43 AM com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal log
INFO: [sqlite] DB[1]: opened
Nov 30, 2014 10:43:43 AM com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal log
INFO: [sqlite] DB[2]: instantiated [/home/rob/.tempusFugit/tfData.sql]
Nov 30, 2014 10:43:43 AM com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal log
INFO: [sqlite] DB[2]: opened
Nov 30, 2014 10:43:43 AM com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal log
INFO: [sqlite] DB[1]: connection closed
Nov 30, 2014 10:43:43 AM com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal log
INFO: [sqlite] DB[3]: instantiated [/home/rob/.tempusFugit/tfData.sql]
Nov 30, 2014 10:43:43 AM com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal log
INFO: [sqlite] DB[3]: opened
10:43:43.507 [SQLiteQueue[tfData.sql]] ERROR nz.co.great_ape.tempusFugit - The database version of /home/rob/.tempusFugit/tfData.sql is unknown.  This is bad.
com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteException: [1] DB[2] prepare() SELECT version, upgraded FROM dbVersion ORDER BY upgraded DESC LIMIT 1; [no such table: dbVersion]
    at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteConnection.throwResult(SQLiteConnection.java:1436) ~[sqlite4java-1.0.392.jar:392]
    at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:580) ~[sqlite4java-1.0.392.jar:392]
    at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:635) ~[sqlite4java-1.0.392.jar:392]
    at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:622) ~[sqlite4java-1.0.392.jar:392]
    at nz.co.great_ape.tempusFugit.DatabaseUpgrade$2.job(DatabaseUpgrade.java:121) [main/:na]
    at nz.co.great_ape.tempusFugit.DatabaseUpgrade$2.job(DatabaseUpgrade.java:117) [main/:na]
    at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteJob.execute(SQLiteJob.java:372) [sqlite4java-1.0.392.jar:392]
    at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteQueue.executeJob(SQLiteQueue.java:534) [sqlite4java-1.0.392.jar:392]
    at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteQueue.queueFunction(SQLiteQueue.java:667) [sqlite4java-1.0.392.jar:392]
    at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteQueue.runQueue(SQLiteQueue.java:623) [sqlite4java-1.0.392.jar:392]
    at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteQueue.access$000(SQLiteQueue.java:77) [sqlite4java-1.0.392.jar:392]
    at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteQueue$1.run(SQLiteQueue.java:205) [sqlite4java-1.0.392.jar:392]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_25]
10:43:43.508 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  nz.co.great_ape.tempusFugit - Database version is unknown.  The file will be deleted and a new database created.  We can survive this.
10:43:43.509 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  nz.co.great_ape.tempusFugit - The database /home/rob/.tempusFugit/tfData.sql has been deleted.
10:43:43.510 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  nz.co.great_ape.tempusFugit - Current Database version is 0
10:43:43.510 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  nz.co.great_ape.tempusFugit - Attempting to upgrade to version 1.
Nov 30, 2014 10:43:43 AM com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal log
INFO: [sqlite] DB[4]: instantiated [/home/rob/.tempusFugit/tfData.sql]
Nov 30, 2014 10:43:43 AM com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal log
INFO: [sqlite] DB[4]: opened
Nov 30, 2014 10:43:43 AM com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal log
INFO: [sqlite] DB[3]: connection closed
10:43:43.640 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  nz.co.great_ape.tempusFugit - The database has been upgraded to version 1.  This is good.
10:43:43.640 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  nz.co.great_ape.tempusFugit - The database is the current version.  This is good.
10:43:43.640 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  nz.co.great_ape.tempusFugit - Created a new database.
10:43:43.640 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  nz.co.great_ape.tempusFugit - Checking the database version is correct.  Looking for version 1.
10:43:43.640 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  nz.co.great_ape.tempusFugit - Checking the database version is correct.  Looking for version 1.
10:43:43.641 [JavaFX Application Thread] ERROR nz.co.great_ape.tempusFugit - Something is wrong, we are not sane.  Aborting...
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at nz.co.great_ape.tempusFugit.DatabaseUpgrade.getVersion(DatabaseUpgrade.java:117) ~[main/:na]
    at nz.co.great_ape.tempusFugit.SanityChecks.DatabaseVersionCorrect(SanityChecks.java:111) ~[main/:na]
    at nz.co.great_ape.tempusFugit.SanityChecks.doBasicChecks(SanityChecks.java:54) ~[main/:na]
    at nz.co.great_ape.tempusFugit.MainApp.start(MainApp.java:78) ~[main/:na]
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$153(LauncherImpl.java:821) [jfxrt.jar:na]
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$56/1015064561.run(Unknown Source) [jfxrt.jar:na]
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$166(PlatformImpl.java:323) [jfxrt.jar:na]
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$50/591723622.run(Unknown Source) [jfxrt.jar:na]
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$164(PlatformImpl.java:292) [jfxrt.jar:na]
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$52/1657335803.run(Unknown Source) [jfxrt.jar:na]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_25]
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$165(PlatformImpl.java:291) [jfxrt.jar:na]
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$51/1166726978.run(Unknown Source) [jfxrt.jar:na]
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95) [jfxrt.jar:na]
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method) [jfxrt.jar:na]
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$45(GtkApplication.java:126) [jfxrt.jar:na]
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication$$Lambda$42/1167116739.run(Unknown Source) [jfxrt.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_25]
10:43:43.641 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  nz.co.great_ape.tempusFugit - Game Over...
10:43:44.563 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  nz.co.great_ape.tempusFugit - Game Over...

Comment: Post the entire error/stack trace.

Comment: Please paste only relevant code and stack trace.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the trace, but I think all the parts of the code are there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is te fact that you call

```
DatabaseUpgrade dug = new DatabaseUpgrade();
logger.info(...);
Integer currentVersion = dug.getVersion();
```

But your `dbConn` and `sQueue` in `DatabaseUpgrade` are still null. Since you didn't called the private `openDatabase()` method which initializes your varaibles. So When you call `getVersion()` your `sQueue.execute(...)` blowups because you cannot call a method on a null object.

Comment: Thank you for that.  Yes a dumb newbie mistake.  Thanks.